# Keep Finder On-Top While Dragging Links From Safari URL Bar

Tags: macos, finder, safari

In the previous version of OS X, Mavericks, I used to be able to have a browser window open and a finder window open, I used to then be able to drag a link from the URL into the finder window to drop links.

If the window was like this:

[image]

Where the finder is on top of the browser you were able to drag the URL link from the URL bar without the safari window jumping up on top. Now when you do it the finder window will get placed under the safari window.

Is there any way to get this property back? Being able to have finder windows on top of the safari window makes it so much easier to drag links from the URL bar to the folder.

Comment: While I am away from my Mac, I know that you at least can use the Cmd+Tab combination while dragging. It may not be ideal, but it would be a workaround to get the Finder window topmost again while dragging the link over.

Answer (score 1):

You can just drag the link to the Finder icon in the Dock, and hold for a couple of seconds. That’s show you all the available windows of Finder, then you can select the one you want to drag the web-loc to. As @Phoenix mentioned in comment, you can aways ⌘+Tab to switch between open apps. Another way would be to use Mission Control, the shortcut of which is F4, or ⌃+↑ (configurable in Keyboard Pref Pane).

It should be expected behaviour to switch to the app you clicked on so Finder has to lose focus, for Safari to respond.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **Tab layout** of **Compact**, hold Command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) then click and drag the URL to a Finder window.  When Command is pressed, the URL icon will show and Finder will remain on top.

If you have **Tab layout** of **Separate** then click the URL bar once (which selects the URL and shows the URL icon) then drag and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Finder.